# Chrome not opening new window correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm attempting to open a new window from a local html file but Chrome doesn't appear to be opening it correctly. I've got the following...

```
    function open()
{
    window.open ("open.html","open","resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no width=500,height=300");
}
```

As you can see, it explains itself. I want a new window of that height with those options. However, right now it opens with scrollbars, is resizeable and doesn't open my html file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing at least one comma there, between toolbar and width.

Comment: A comma is missing after toolbar=no.

Comment: It works fine for me in chrome 8, as long as i don't call the function "open" :)

Comment: The name open is creating ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the missing comma and change your function name from `open` to something else (say `openLink`).

Comment: I also thought it was that missing comma..but it isn't working.. it seems to ignore the parameters..chrome 8.0 (win7)